# How can I determine which Firefox profiles is used during a selenium test?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I inherited some java-based selenium tests, and have been tasked with running them against a secured site.
The scripts are work fine when the site is not secured.

When I run the tests against the secured site I get an error saying that there ris a handshake exception. I assumed that the problem is that Firefox is not accepting the site certificates.

I used openssl to download the site's ssl certificate and used certutil (on linux) to add the certificate to the cert8.db in the Firefox profile I configured for this testing.

However even after adding the certificate I am still getting the same handshake exception. I wonder if Firefox is not using the profile I specified for the testing.

Is there any way to determine which profile Firefox is using for a selenium test?

BTW: the `profiles.ini` file for firefox has `"default=1"` for the profile I wish to use.

Comment: You should add the code that produces the exception and the exception itself with a stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Firefox profile you want when creating the webdriver instance. There is a constructor for that. That way you don't have to check for the profile later. Or is there a good reason to do otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the remote end of the `webdriver` creates a new profile while creating a new session unless specified.
If you are using a custom profile, then you must be passing the instance of the profile as an argument to the driver object.